# Visual C++ 2008 x86 SP1 redist debugging symbols can't be found by Visual Studio 2008

Tags: debug-symbols, visual-c++-2008, redistributable

For some reason, Visual Studio can't seem to find the debugging symbols for VC++ 2008 SP1 Redist (this one: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5582&WT.mc_id=MSCOM_EN_US_DLC_DETAILS_121LSUS007998). Does anybody have a clue why the symbols aren't available on Microsoft's standard symbol servers? Are there any other symbol servers that I'm not aware of?

If this is way off topic for SO, let me know. My level of frustration is through the roof...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was facing was finding out why a crash had occurred on a Windows XP machine. My development machine is Windows 7. The MFC DLLs are loaded from WinSxS. Of course, the DLLs on the target machine differs from the DLLs on my development machine. The simple solution was to place the target machine's MFC DLLs on my dev machine next to the binaries and dump file.